# How do I reference a bean in spring-el named with a prefix?

Tags: spring, spring-el

As far as I know, I can inject sth by using spring-el like

```
<property name="someProperty" value="#{someBean.aMethod()}" />
```

But our code convention requires name bean with a prefix like

```
<bean id="{moduleName.ClassName}" />
```

This will cause spring-el resolve moduleName as a bean which does not exist.

Is there some way to escape the dot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<property name="someProperty" value="#{@'moduleName.ClassName'.aMethod()}" />` .

Hope this helps.